# How to control multiple buttons with a single name to request a response from weather API

Tags: javascript, html

I have a list of 8 city names that are populated from a previous search via local storage. I need to use the city name to submit an API weather request and don't know how to manage the individual buttons. Right now when I click on the name of the city once it shows up in my previous search list, I am not able to get a response from the API.

Here's my HTML code:

```
 <div class="list-group" class="previousCities">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city1">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city2">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city3">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city4">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city5">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city6">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city7">
                    <input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city8">
                </div>
```

Here's my CSS code:

```
var savedCities = document.querySelector('cities');
    var newCity = document.getElementById('button');

    $('button').on('click', function() {

        console.log('press')

    event.preventDefault()

    var savedCities = document.querySelector('cities').value;

    //API key & query variables
    var myKey = "ada1f715672a438e9b9acaa7ea0e930b";

    var queryURL1 =`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=${myKey}`

    $.ajax({
        url: queryURL1,
        method: "GET"
    })
    .then(function(response) {

    console.log(queryURL1);  

    console.log(response);

    $(".city").html("<h3>" + response.city.name + "</h3>");
    $("#icon").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[0].weather[0].icon +".png'>");
    $(".temp").text("Temperature: " + response.list[0].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".wind").text("Wind Speed: " + response.list[0].wind.speed);
    $(".humidity").text("Humidity: " + response.list[0].main.humidity + " %");
    //$(".uvIndex").text("UV Index: " + response.main.humidity);

    $(".icon1").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[1].weather[0].icon +".png'>");
    $(".temp1").text("Temp: " + response.list[1].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".humidity1").text("Humidity: " + response.list[1].main.humidity + " %");

    $(".icon2").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[2].weather[0].icon +".png'>");
    $(".temp2").text("Temp: " + response.list[2].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".humidity2").text("Humidity: " + response.list[1].main.humidity + " %");

    $(".icon3").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[3].weather[0].icon +".png'>");
    $(".temp3").text("Temp: " + response.list[3].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".humidity3").text("Humidity: " + response.list[1].main.humidity + " %");

    $(".icon4").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[4].weather[0].icon +".png'>"); 
    $(".temp4").text("Temp: " + response.list[4].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".humidity4").text("Humidity: " + response.list[1].main.humidity + " %");

    $(".icon5").html("<img src='http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/" + response.list[5].weather[0].icon +".png'>"); 
    $(".temp5").text("Temp: " + response.list[5].main.temp.toFixed(0) + " °");
    $(".humidity5").text("Humidity: " + response.list[1].main.humidity + " %");
        })
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 *class* atribute for each button: `<input class="favorite styled" type="button" value="" class="cities" id="city1">`, so you can't get them with `document.querySelectorAll(".cities")` nor `$(".cities")`.

Fix them by appending *cities* to the first *class* attribute `<input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="" id="city1">`

Another error you have is that you're trying to append the click event on `$('button')`, but you don't have button tags in your HTML, you have input tags with button type, so you should access them by `$('input[type="button"]')` or by it's class `$(".cities")`

```js
$(function() {
    $(".cities").on('click', function() {
        //API key & query variables
        let myKey = "ada1f715672a438e9b9acaa7ea0e930b";
        // Now you can get button value
        let cityName = $(this).val();
        let queryURL1 =`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=${cityName}&units=imperial&appid=${myKey}`
        // Fetch data below
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group" class="previousCities">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="New York" id="city1">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="London" id="city2">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Mexico City" id="city3">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Buenos Aires" id="city4">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Berlin" id="city5">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Paris" id="city6">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Sao Paulo" id="city7">
                    <input class="favorite styled cities" type="button" value="Roma" id="city8">
                </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give that a shot.